# Query to select records in one table that have a record existing in another table

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables:

```
Appointments    (CustomerID,AppointmentID,SalesRepID,Status,AppointmentDate)

ResultedSales   (CustomerID,AppointmentID,ResultedDate)
```

I am looking for records in Appointments where:

1. The status is resulted (As opposed to pending, canceled, open, etc)
2. The Customer has been sold to previously (CustomerID in ResultedSales)
3. The Appointment was not resulted as a sale (AppointmentID not in ResultedSales)
4. The Appointment occurs after the first time the customer was sold to
   (AppointmentDate > AppointmentDate of the smallest AppointmentID record in ResultedSales for that CustomerID)
5. The SalesRep who was assigned to the appointment is the same as the previous sale
   (SalesRepID = SalesRepID of any AppointmentID record in ResultedSales for that CustomerID)

The first three are achieved with

```
Select Distinct .AppointmentID from Appointments A
    join ResultedSales RS on A.CustomerID=RS.CustomerID
Where A.StatusID='resulted'
And A.CustomerID in (Select CustomerIDfrom ResultedSales)
And A.AppointmentID Not in (select AppointmentID from ResultedSales)
```

But I cannot figure out how to achieve #4 and #5

Any help/tips?

Comment: You have a mismatch between your explanation and your code. Code references ReportedSales, question references ResultedSales.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I edited the post to correct.

Comment: LeadID is meant to be CustomerID, sorry about that.

Comment: The `And A.CustomerID in (Select CustomerID from ResultedSales)` does nothing. You're already limiting your resultset in the join to records that match up with customerID from ResultedSales. You probably need some additional logic to actually get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Distinct .AppointmentID from Appointments A
    join ReportedSales RS on A.CustomerID=RS.CustomerID
Where A.StatusID='resulted'

and exists ( select null from ResultedSales innerRSTable1 where innerRSTable1.CustomerID = A.CustomerID)
and not exists ( select null from ResultedSales innerRSTable2 where innerRSTable2.AppointmentID = A.AppointmentID )
```

Comment: This one is still selecting Appointment records which occurred before the first ResultedSales record.

Edit: Looks like it is also selecting records from Appointments where the SalesRepID does not match the SalesRepID from the appointment that exists in ResultedSales.

Comment: You're gonna have to post the DDL. And maybe some INSERT statements.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the MSDN information on `EXISTS` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx

```
Select  Distinct A.AppointmentID 
from    Appointments A
join    ResultedSales RS 
        on  A.CustomerID=RS.CustomerID
Where   A.StatusID='resulted'
And     Not Exists (Select 1 
                    From    ResultedSales rs2
                    Where   A.AppointmentID = rs2.AppointmentID)
And     Exists (Select  1
                From    Appointments A2
                Where   A.CustomerID=A2.CustomerID
                And     A.AppointmentDate > A2.AppointmentDate)
And     Exists (Select  1
                From    Appointments A3
                Where   A.CustomerID=A3.CustomerID
                And     A.SalesRepID = A2.SalesRepID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Got another response from a different forum that seems to do what the query was calling for.

```
;WITH FirstSales (CustomerID, AppointmentDate, SalesRepID)
AS (
SELECT DISTINCT 
   A.CustomerID
   , MIN(AppointmentDate)
   , A.SalesRepID
FROM ResultedSales RS
JOIN Appointments A
   ON A.AppointmentID = RS.AppointmentID 
   AND A.CustomerID = RS.CustomerID
WHERE StatusID = 'Resulted'
GROUP BY A.CustomerID, A.SalesRepID
)

SELECT DISTINCT 
    A.AppointmentID
FROM Appointments A
    JOIN ResultedSales RS
        ON RS.CustomerID = A.CustomerID
    JOIN FirstSales FS
        ON FS.CustomerID = A.CustomerID
WHERE A.StatusID = 'Resulted'
AND A.AppointmentDate > FS.AppointmentDate
AND A.SalesRepID = FS.SalesRepID
AND A.AppointmentID Not in (select AppointmentID from ResultedSales)
```